# jQuery datepicker: Limit date from selectedDate

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'd like to restrict my calendar for users to limit date range.

For example: if a user select March 10th 2014 at From, then the user must not select after June 10th 2014 at To.

Here is the code I've made:

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      maxDate: 0,
      dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var maxDate = new Date(date.getMonth() + 3);
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate );
      }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the month from From datepicker and increment to 3 months for maxDate of the To datepicker.

```
$("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",            
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 3);
            $('#to').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {                
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(from);
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
            if (to <= from) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#from').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/586/

Comment: Thank you. that was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the way in which you're using dates. Please, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxbto2hx/2/)

You have to parse the date to a valid format before assigning it to the maxDate or minDate option ofthe datepicker:

```
        var arr = selectedDate.split("-");
        var date = new Date(arr[2] + "-" + arr[1] + "-" + arr[0]);
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var minDate = new Date(y, m + 1, d);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
        //var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var maxDate = new Date(y, m + 3, d);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);
```

The same applies to the other datepicker:

```
        var arr = selectedDate.split("-");
        var date = new Date(arr[2] + "-" + arr[1] + "-" + arr[0]);
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function() {
  $( "#to").datepicker();
  $( "#from").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
           $( "#to").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
           $( "#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
           var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
           var maxDate = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
           $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate );
  }
});
```